# array over non-existing indices in awk

Tags: awk

Sorry for the verbose question, it boils down to a very simple problem.
Assume there are n text files each containing one column of strings (denominating groups) and one of integers (denominating the values of instances within these groups):

```
  # filename xxyz.log
  a 5  
  a 6  
  b 10  
  b 15  
  c 101  
  c 100  

  #filename xyzz.log
  a 3  
  a 5  
  c 116  
  c 128
```

Note that while the length of both columns within any given file is always identical it differs between files. Furthermore, not all files contain the same range of groups (the first one contains groups a, b, c, while the second one only contains groups a and c). In awk one could calculate the average of column 2 for each string in column 1 within each file separately and output the results with the following code:

```
  NAMES=$(ls|grep .log|awk -F'.' '{print $1}');

  for q in $NAMES;
  do
    gawk -F' ' -v y=$q 'BEGIN {print "param", y}
    {sum1[$1] += $2; N[$1]++}
    END     {for (key in sum1) {
                       avg1 = sum1[key] / N[key];
                       printf "%s %f\n", key, avg1;
                   } }' $q.log | sort > $q.mean;
  done;
```

Howerver, for the abovementioned reasons, the length of the resulting .mean files differs between files. For each .log file I'd like to output a .mean file listing the entire range of groups (a-d) in the first column and the corresponding mean value or empty spaces in the second column depending on whether this category is present in the .log file. I've tried the following code (given without $NAMES for brevity):

```
  awk 'BEGIN{arr[a]="a"; arr[b]="b"; arr[c]="c"; arr[d]="d"} 
  {sum[$1] += $2; N[$1]++} 
  END {for (i in arr) {
  if (i in sum) {
    avg = sum[i] / N[i]; 
    printf "%s %f\n" i, avg;} 
  else {
    printf "%s %s\n" i, "";}
  }}' xxyz.log > xxyz.mean;
```

but it returns the following error:

```
awk: (FILENAME=myfile FNR=7) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `%s %s
'
            ^ ran out for this one
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will you ever have explicit zeroes or negative numbers in the log files?  I'm going to assume not.

The first line of your second script doesn't do what you wanted:

```
awk 'BEGIN{arr[a]="a"; arr[b]="b"; arr[c]="c"; arr[d]="d"}
```

This assigns `"a"` to `arr[0]` (because `a` is a variable not previously used), then `"b"` to the same element (because `b` is a variable not previously used), then `"c"`, then `"d"`.  Clearly, not what you had in mind.  This (untested) code should do the job you need as long as you know that there are just the four groups.  If you don't know the groups a priori, you need a more complex program (it can be done, but it is harder).

```
awk 'BEGIN { sum["a"] = 0; sum["b"] = 0; sum["c"] = 0; sum["d"] = 0 } 
     { sum[$1] += $2; N[$1]++ } 
     END {   for (i in sum) {
                 if (N[i] == 0) N[i] = 1 # Divide by zero protection
                 avg = sum[i] / N[i]; 
                 printf "%s %f\n" i, avg;
             } 
         }' xxyz.log > xxyz.mean;
```

This will print a zero average for the missing groups.  If you prefer, you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN { sum["a"] = 0; sum["b"] = 0; sum["c"] = 0; sum["d"] = 0 } 
     { sum[$1] += $2; N[$1]++ } 
     END {   for (i in sum) {
                 if (N[i] == 0)
                     printf("%s\n", i;
                 else {
                     avg = sum[i] / N[i]; 
                     printf "%s %f\n" i, avg;
                 }
             } 
         }' xxyz.log > xxyz.mean;
```

Comment: First, thanks for the thorough explanation: now I know what I did wrong. Second, both code snippets you propose are working when a single comma is added after "%s %f\n" (my mistake, I had forgotten it in my original question). Third, the second code you suggested outputs precisely what I need. Fourth, for clarification: no, the log files contain no explicit zeros or negative numbers. Fifth, yes, I know the groups a priori. If I didn't, couldn't I build something around the first line proposed by Catcall?

Comment: (2) My bad for not spotting too (but the 'untested' warning was there for a purpose). (5) Yes, something along those lines would be necessary (preprocess the files to get the list of categories, and then some way of getting the list of categories into the script; there's more than one way of dealing with that).

Answer (score 1):

> For each .log file I'd like to output a .mean file listing the entire
>   range of groups (a-d) in the first column and the corresponding mean
>   value or empty spaces in the second column depending on whether this
>   category is present in the .log file.

Not purely an awk solution, but you can get all the groups with this.

```
awk '{print $1}' *.log | sort -u > groups
```

After you calculate the means, you can then join the groups file. Let's say the means for your second input file look like this temporary, intermediate file. (I called it xyzz.tmp.)

```
a 4
c 122
```

Join the groups, preserving all the values from the groups file.

```
$ join -a1 groups xyzz.tmp > xyzz.mean
$ cat xyzz.mean
a 4
b
c 122
```

Comment: An elegant solution. Thank you very much for drawing my attention to "join" which I've obviously neglected for too long.

Comment: Of course, the code doesn't list category "d" which does not occur in any of the files.

Comment: That's true. But if you want to add categories that don't exist in any of the files, just add that category (manually, or through some sensible automation) to the file "groups". And sort that file. The `join` utility requires both input files be sorted on their join fields. See `man join` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on the problem. Run like:

```
./script.sh
```

Contents of `script.sh`:

```
array=($(awk '!a[$1]++ { print $1 }' *.log))

readarray -t sorted < <(for i in "${array[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done | sort)

for i in *.log; do
    for j in "${sorted[@]}"; do
        awk -v var=$j '
            {
                sum[$1]+=$2
                cnt[$1]++
            }
            END {
                print var, (var in cnt ? sum[var]/cnt[var] : "")
            }
        ' "$i" >> "${i/.log/.main}"
    done
done
```

Results of `grep . *.main`:

```
xxyz.main:a 5.5
xxyz.main:b 12.5
xxyz.main:c 100.5
xyzz.main:a 4
xyzz.main:b 
xyzz.main:c 122
```

Comment: Thanks for the plug-and-play answer! But, as far as I understand the code (and its output), it does not provide a solution for the case that there are categories which do not occur in any of the files (e.g. category "d" in my question).

Comment: @skitnik: Sorry -- I think I may have not fully understood your question (or have made one too many assumptions). I now see that you wanted those groups (a-d) hardcoded. The version above first checks to see what groups are available in all log files. Since group 'd' was not present in the two input files provided, it remains absent from the output. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure awk answer:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.log" -print0 | 
  xargs -0 awk '{SUBSEP=" ";sum[FILENAME,$1]+=$2;cnt[FILENAME,$1]+=1;next}
  END{for(i in sum)print i, sum[i], cnt[i], sum[i]/cnt[i]}'
```

Easy enough to push this into a file --

Comment: Thanks. This works after changing "log.*" to "*.log" but does not output what I need. Instead, it returns the sums, cnt, and averages for each category over all files.

Comment: ahhh ... averages for each file -- sorry I misunderstood that. i suppose too late now, but that just calls for a SUBSEP... see update.  Went for a concise answer here :)

Comment: This version calculates the sum, cnt, and average for each category in each file but does not output category d (in any of the files) or category b in the second file ;-) Thanks anyway!